# Output on strip() string is not expected

Tags: python, string, strip

The output on the strip() function doesn't give the expected output. I'm looking for just 'interfaces'

```
>>> template = 'interfaces.jinja2'
>>> template.strip('.jinja2')     
'terfaces'
```

Comment: `strip()` strips off characters from ends which includes `'in'` at the beginning as well. How about `template.split('.')[0]` ?

Comment: Just use `template.replace('.jinja2', '')` which returns `'interfaces'`.

Comment: Strip strips off the characters you provided in '.jinja2' from the outside of the string until a character in the string doesn't match those provided.  Since 'interfaces' and 'jinja2' share 'i', 'a,' and 'n,' strip takes off the 'i' and 'n,' but stops once it hits 't,' so 'a' is never dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> template = 'interfaces.jinja2'
>>> template.split('.')
```

['interfaces','jninja2']

```
>>> template.split('.')[0]
```

interfaces